# Charge a user on both sender and receiver chain of an XCM `Transact` with `OriginKind::Native`

Tags: xcm, xcmp

Use case:

Alice submits an extrinsic on chain A which, among other things, sends an XCM message including a `Transact` operation to chain B.

On chain A, Alice pays for the extrinsic execution. What I am trying to do, is to let Alice also pay with her account on chain B.

The XCM that is composed inside the extrinsic is the following:

```
[
  DescendOrigin(
    AccountId32 {
      network: None,
      id: dispatcher.into(),
    }.into(),
  ),
  WithdrawAsset(asset.clone().into()),
  BuyExecution {
    fees: asset,
    weight_limit: Unlimited,
  },
  Transact {
    origin_kind: OriginKind::Native,
    require_weight_at_most: weight,
    call: dest_tx,
  }
]
```

where `dispatcher` is the signed origin on chain A, `asset` and `weight` are parameters of the extrinsic and must be under the control of Alice on chain B.

Clearly, I could only use a `OriginKind::Native` since otherwise the call would not have the parachain priviledge.
Nevertheless, I cannot get the `Transact` to be executed without getting a `BadOrigin` error. It does not seem possible, right now, to have an `OriginConverter` which accepts a `Multilocation` of type `../Parachain(x)/AccountId(acc)`.
The `LocationConverter` works fine with just using the provided `Account32Hash<(), AccountId>`, although a [new PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/6662) is in the making to address this. On the contrary, origin conversion does not seem to be supported, and of course any attempt to insert a `ClearOrigin` call before the `Transact` would fail.

Is calling `UniversalOrigin` the only way to charge a user on chain B for the execution of the `Transact`? Or is there some other way to charge the user on chain B while still making sure that only the chain A can indeed send such XCM message? An `OriginKind::SoverignAccount` does not seem to be good for our case since everyone could just send it via the XCM pallet, while chain A wants to give chain B guarantees that the messages has higher priviledge then a simple user.